# Ubuntu 12.04, Unity launcher missing

Tags: 12.04, unity, compiz

I am new user I just messed up some option in compiz Config Manager and it has to do with Unity. I was on CompizConfigSettings Manager menu and I clicked one of the options and whole Unity tray GONE! I also can't se Time and Date. So basically since I installed it yesterday I don't know about shortcuts in Ubuntu and how to restart it. Basically I am stuck on desktop background, it is only thing I can see.I managed to run Nautilus and access the Web browser. So If somebody can tell me how to access terminal or to restart Unity(if I only can see Dash or terminal).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> for opening a terminal.

You can try the folowing commands for restarting (or start) compiz or unity in terminal.

```
compiz
unity
```

If this not work try to restore you setting using:

```
ccsm
```

go to preferences, select unity and press restore default.

Comment: It was problem with Unity plugin, I turned some windows effect an then turned off Unity plugin. I dint know for terminal compiz shorcut. Well explained.

Comment: You need to watch out witch some settings in compizconfig. Can you improve your question a little bit? So other users can fast read what your problem is?

Comment: Ok, I will try to make it shorter.